# Memory exception using SMARTXLS api in Pivot table creation

Tags: c#

I am creating an pivot excel which has 909k rows and 10 columns. I am getting a "System.out of memory" exception when it comes to 6th field. Can any one help me out with this? I am using `SMARTXLS` api in c#.